# trying to perform full import to a solr instance using tomcat

Tags: java, solr, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to create a new `solr` instance and then perform a full import on it in a Spring application using `Tomcat`, however I keep getting:

> ERROR 1440 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.s.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient  : Request to collection (collection name here) failed due to (510) org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find a healthy node to handle the request

I think it's very possible that I'm not uploading the necessary configuration files right, but I am not sure.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have active Shards in your zookeeper's /clusterstate.json znode.

We can access this data from solr admin request on one of the solr node in the cloud:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=clusterstatus&wt=json&indent=on"
```

Your collection should be listed here. All shards of your collection should have `"state":"active"`.